# data being sent but not being included in pdf file

Tags: php, mpdf

Im using mpdf to generate pdf which works great,
but when I send data from js that being sent perfectly but not included my pdf

tried to send the data in different ways and include it in php as

```
$name=$_post['name'];
```

and use the variable `$name`
or write it directly as `$_post['name']`.

ps.when I create a variable such as `$name="namename"`
it can be included

```
require_once __DIR__ . '../vendor/autoload.php';



$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();

$style = '<style>'.file_get_contents('pdf_styles.css') . '</style>';


$name = $_POST['first_name'];

$name2="namename";




$firstpage = $mpdf->AddPage(); //cover page


//header of first page


$data .= '<div class="centered">'.'<h1>'. $name . '</h1>' . '</div>' . '<br/>' . '</br>';


$mpdf->WriteHTML($style);
$mpdf->WriteHTML($data);
```

....

no error msgs

Comment: You say data is being sent, but I suspect it's not. You say if you put data directly into `$name` it works fine. That tells me that either you're referencing the wrong key in `$_POST` or the key is empty. Maybe `print_r($_POST);` to see what your data actually looks like, or use your browser's developer tools to look at the actual request being sent.

Comment: $name=`$_post['name'];` should be `$name=$_POST['name'];` is a super global variable.

Comment: `$_post` is **NOT** the same as `$_POST`. Anywhere you are using the former change it to the latter and see what happens.